# Customize AppBar Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, scroll

I am developing a workout app and I need help with a few features that are located in the app bar. First of all, there is a greenish circle that appears in the top left - ideally, I would like that circle to shrink towards the left corner and disappear completely when the user scrolls past a certain point instead of just moving out of the screen when the user scrolls down. In addition I have a profile image that I would like to start at 75 pixels and then as the user scrolls, I would like it to get to 50 pixels in width and settle into place next to the Premium button.

Here is an image with arrows pointing to where I want the features to relocate too when the user scrolls:
[image: Screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SizedBox.expand(
        child: GestureDetector(
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  PageTransition(
                    type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight,
                    child: explore_page(),
                  ),
                );
              }
              if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  PageTransition(
                    type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                    child: workout_page(),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            child: Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 67, 67, 67)),
                child: GestureDetector(
                    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                    onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
                      if (_dragStart == 0) {
                        _dragStart = details.globalPosition.dy;
                      } else {
                        final dragDistance =
                            details.globalPosition.dy - _dragStart;
                        _scrollController.animateTo(
                          _scrollController.offset - dragDistance,
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                          curve: Curves.easeOut,
                        );
                        _dragStart = details.globalPosition.dy;
                      }
                    },
                    onVerticalDragEnd: (_) {
                      _dragStart = 0;
                    },
                    child: Scaffold(
                        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(10, 159, 159, 159),
                        body: Stack(children: [
                          CustomScrollView(
                            slivers: [
                              SliverAppBar(
                                expandedHeight: 185,
                                titleSpacing: 15,
                                pinned: true,
                                backgroundColor:
                                    Color.fromARGB(255, 69, 69, 69),
                                centerTitle: false,
                                bottom: PreferredSize(
                                  preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    width: size.width * .7,
                                    child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.star_purple500_sharp,
                                          color: Colors.black),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      label: Transform.translate(
                                          offset: Offset(-4, 2),
                                          child: Text('Go Premium!',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontWeight:
                                                      FontWeight.bold))),
                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                          shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                                          backgroundColor:
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 255, 8)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                                  collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                                  background: Stack(
                                    children: [
                                      Positioned(
                                        top: -size.width * .08,
                                        left: -size.width * .08,
                                        child: Transform.translate(
                                          offset: const Offset(-30, -30),
                                          child: const CircleButton(),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Positioned(
                                        left: size.width * .2,
                                        top: size.height * .09,
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            const Text('JustLift',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                        255, 252, 250, 250),
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    fontSize: 50)),
                                            Transform.translate(
                                              offset: Offset(0, -10),
                                              child: Text(
                                                element,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                  color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                      255, 224, 224, 224),
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize: 20,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                                child: Stack(children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height: size.height * .9,
                                    child: Text('asdf',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 300)),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                      height: size.height * .9,
                                      child: Text('asdf',
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 300))),
                                  SizedBox(height: 300)
                                ]),
                              ),
  ],
                          ),
                          Footer(tab: 'Home'),
                          Image.asset('assets/images/user.png',
                              width: 55 /*70 to 55 when user srolls*/)
                        ]))))));
  }


class CircleButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CircleButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .45;

    return InkResponse(
      child: Container(
        width: size,
        height: size,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 166, 255, 0),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you so much in advance!!!!